# i need to create a text file that contains the output of my function in haskell

Tags: haskell

I just want to write something on the code that creates a text file that contains the output of a function. I want to specify the name of the text file on the code

Like: create a file named "output.txt" that contains the output of the function rectangleArea.

How do I turn thsi into code?

I haven't tried anything yet because i really have no idea how this works. I've read tutorials but I still couldn't find a way to do this.

Comment: So you want your program to, like, [write a file](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=writeFile)?

Comment: yes. i have 5 functions in my code. when i run my program, the user has to chose between 6 options. the first 5 options runs one of the functions. the sixth option prints the outputs of the functions on a text file "output.txt" but, for now, this option does nothing because i don't know how to create a code line that does it...

Comment: Well then show what you have tried!

Comment: and i tried this writeFile but it didn't work

Comment: @user3741052, `writeFile` is the function you want probably. "it didn't work" is not very descriptive -- show us how you used it, how it failed (e.g. error message? didn't create the file?) and we will help you use it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Well then lets try something like this:

```
main = writeFile filename $ show $ func parameters
```

For your case this would be something like this:

```
main = writeFile "output.txt" $ show $ rectangleArea parameter1 parameter2
```

A small working example:

```
main = do
  width <- fmap read $ getLine
  height <- fmap read $ getLine
  filename <- getLine
  writeFile filename $ show $ rectangleArea width height

rectangleArea w h = w * h
```

---

Getting input by the user works best when using `getLine`, like this for example:

```
main = do
    name <- getLine
    print ("Hello " ++ name)
```

For further information on in- and output in Haskell I strongly recommend [this](http://learnyouahaskell.com/input-and-output) chapter from the LYAH tutorial as it covers the basics extremely well and will help you with your problem.

Comment: i did: print = writeFile "output.txt" $ show $ rectangleArea base height

Comment: but when i try to compile it says that the parameters are not in scope

Comment: @user3741052 There lies the problem. How can rectangleArea compute base * height if it **does not know the values**?

Comment: i understood that. but i don't know how to make it know the values

Comment: @user3741052 If you understood it you would know how to do this and not ask for help

Comment: the problem is that the parameters are variables. the user inputs them ex.: rectangleArea 3 2 then it outputs 6 and i want to create a text file to store this value.

Comment: @user3741052 Please have a look at the small working example. It covers everything you need.

Comment: thanks! one more thing. i wrote the code exactly like the smal working example: main = do
  base <- fmap read $ getLine
  height <- fmap read $ getLine
  filename <- getLine
  writeFile "output.txt" $ show $ rectangleArea base height

rectangleArea base height = base * height

Comment: the file was created but there's nothing written in there!

Comment: How did you run the program? Did you try just writing a single string as a test?

Comment: i didn't run it at hugs/ghci. I ran it at the terminal like: ghc --make test

Comment: i only wrote this: rectangleArea base height = base * height

main = do
 base <- fmap read $ getLine
 height <- fmap read $ getLine
 writeFile "output.txt" $ show $ rectangleArea base height